# IIS and incoming domain redirection

Tags: redirect, iis, dns

I have inherited a clients IIS server and know diddly squat about server management. 
The task in hand is apparently quite simple.

Redirect www.domain.com to our server ip and point it to a directory within my server.

So far I have amended the Domain name to point at our servers IP address......
and now I am stumped.

I have set up the site on the server and set the Home Directory to point to the appropriate directory on the server eg mysite/new but still am missing something as all I get is 'Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)'

Any clues or pointers would be appreciated!

Spike

Comment: Check basic setting of application in its. The host name should be same as domain name.. Also it is better to mention the response code..are you able to ping your server?

Comment: I'd recommend ServerFault for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a couple of assumptions.  Please correct me if I'm wrong and I will update the instructions properly.  1.  You are running the latest IIS.  2.  You are running multiples sites on this server.

There are a couple of ways to do this.  The best way is with Host Headers.  Basically, the browser sends the server the desired host in the headers and the server sends you there.

Setup your site and right click on it.  Select "Edit Bindings" and edit the binding for the ip/port you have setup.  Enter your hostname eg: www.domain.com.  Press OK and you are done.

Here is a technet article dealing with this topic:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Bobby, some more details:
The Server is IIS 6 with multiple site running on it.

This Domain should point to a subdirectory of an existing site - does it need it's own web.config file for this to work? 

I have recreated the site in IIS adding in the host headers as described in the article with some success however now it insists on downloading the file instead of serving it.

Comment: The web.config depends on your site but isn't required.  

The issue with downloading the file instead of server it is that you don't have the proper role services turned on in IIS.  For example; if this is an ASP.net site when you added the Web Server roll, you need to also add the asp.net roll service. 

The first technet article below defines the available roll services, you can see that asp.net is available but not default.  The second article explains how to add a roll.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd632616.aspx

Comment: Thanks Bobby, your help is appreciated. 

I have now registered an Application Pool, activated it and it's in use. 
I changed the version of ASP to 2.05 in the ASP.NET tab and that stopped the downloading.....

Now I have an EMPTY_RESPONSE code from Chrome and a RESET error from Firefox. 

This is why I never paid for hosting!

I feel we are getting closer!

Comment: Chrome - Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE 
FF - The connection was reset

Comment: Unfortunately that one isn't very helpful.  Do you have access to the server logs?  It looks like the server is dropping the connection.

Comment: Bobby, I finally decided to just add a redirect to the incoming domain rather than bang my head with this much further. Thank you for your help and guidance.